# Proguard keep overriden methods inside interfaces that extends another interface

Tags: java, interface, proguard

i have two interfaces

```
public interface Base {
   void methA();
   void methB();
   void methC();
}
```

and

```
public interface Sub extends Base {
   @MyAnnotation("a")
   void methA();
   @MyAnnotation("b")
   void methB();
   @MyAnnotation("c")
   void methC();
   @MyAnnotation("d")
   void methD();
   @MyAnnotation("e")
   void methE();
}
```

after proguard i have this two interfaces

```
public interface a{
   void a();
   void b();
   void c();
}
```

and

```
public interface b extends a{
   @MyAnnotation("d")
   void d();
   @MyAnnotation("e")
   void e();
}
```

but for the second one i would need

```
public interface b extends a{
   @MyAnnotation("a")
   void a();
   @MyAnnotation("b")
   void b();
   @MyAnnotation("c")
   void c();
   @MyAnnotation("d")
   void d();
   @MyAnnotation("e")
   void e();
}
```

that means, i need the override methods with thier annotations. i don't care the method names i just need the annotations.

i CAN'T set the annotations for `a`, `b` and `c` in the Base interface as i have 2 (maybe later more) Sub interfaces that set other values for `@MyAnnotation`

so, is there a way to tell proguard to keep the duplicate method names in the subinterface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution! :)

`-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation,allowoptimization interface * extends path.to.my.interface.Base{*;}`

this more or less disables shrinking for any interface that extends the `Base` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Proguard has a dedicated flag to disable optimizations. General notation is:

```
-dontoptimize
```

It will, however, turn off all the optimizations, which may be not desirable in your particular case. Actualy you can choose which optimization to disable by explicitly stating an optimization filter:

```
-dontoptimize optimization_filter_name
```

I'm not 100% sure which one can help here, but I suspect `class/merging/vertical` filter to be responsible for interface duplicate method removal. You can find optimizations list [here](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#manual/optimizations.html) and try which one helps.

Comment: i have 
`-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*` which already should disable merging? An optimization that is preceded by an exclamation mark '!' is excluded from further attempts to match with subsequent optimization names in the filter.

Comment: even when i comment my `-optimizations` line and add `-dontoptimize` the methods were removed :(

Comment: hmmm, that means the actual reason is not the optimization. Try to disable shrinking with '-dontshrink'

Comment: yea, after looking some more i fond the shrinking stuff too. but i found a better way than disable shrinking for the whole code with `-dontshrink` take a look at my answer for the way to go.